# Geckofx 45 sends error code 253 when draw to bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, geckofx

i have a problem with taking screenshot of Gecko 45.

Here is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height);
browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0,0,browser.Width,browser.Height));
bitmap.Save("Screenshots/test.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

This is console output:

```
'WpfApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.mshtml\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.mshtml.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The program '[5056] WpfApplication1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 253 (0xfd).
```